# What happen when two module override same file?

Tags: magento2, overrides

I am coming from Wordpress development & now I started Magento module development.

I am following [this](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-social-share-buttons-magento-2/) tutorial.

I am just trying to add social sharing buttons to the product edit page.

According to their article,

> Now go to the root directory of your Magento and navigate to
>   vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view,
>   and find the addtocart.phtml  file.
>
> Copy this file to your module in
>   app/code/Cloudways/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view

So you can see that we are going to override the addtocart.phtml. So my question is, what happens another module override same file? Loss my changes?

Comment: it depends on the modules sequence

Comment: @PhilippSander It means, if two modules override the same file, definitely one module doesn't work as expected?

Comment: can't say that per-say. it depends on what the modules do

Answer (score 1):

It depends on sequence of your module.

In module.xml you add all modules on which your module depends. Magento will make sure to load your module after all of these modules.

Example

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ComponentB" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
        <!-- Vendor_ComponentB is dependent on Vendor_ComponentA: -->
            <module name="Vendor_ComponentA" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

The module which will load in the end will overwrite the files of previous modules.

app/code/etc/config.php is auto generated file which has all modules list and modules loading sequence.

Comment: and your theme will always overwrite module templates

Comment: Question is about when module override same file. It is not about frontend theme.

Comment: @IsmailZafar It means, if two modules override the same file, definitely one module doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson  see this file app/code/etc/config.php. The module which comes later  can overwrite the module which comes earlier.